# What is the dual for the following LP

Tags: linear-programming

Minimize $c^Tx$

subject to, $b_l \leq Ax \leq b_u \\ l\leq x \leq u$

where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.

My approach was to separate each inequality into two.
So,

$b_l \leq Ax\\
Ax\leq b_u\\
l\leq x\\
x\leq u$

And the dual objective would then be,
Maximize $b_l^Ty+b_u^Ty+l^Ty+u^Ty$. I was not able to figure out the constraints

Comment: Rewrite as $\min c^Tx$ subject to $Bx\le d$, $x$ free.

Comment: @A.Γ. I can make $x$ free via $x=x_1-x_2$,$x_1,x_2 \geq 0$ but how do I remove the lower bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be the identity matrix. Define
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}A\\-A\\I\\-I\end{bmatrix},\qquad d=\begin{bmatrix}b_l\\-b_u\\l\\-u\end{bmatrix}
$$
then all the constraints can be written as $Bx\ge d$.

Calculate the dual problem to
$$
\min c^Tx\quad\text{subject to }Bx\ge d.
$$
There are different ways to do it in optimization courses that covers LP, but let's do it via Lagrange duality. The Lagrange function is
$$
L(x,y)=c^Tx+y^T(d-Bx)=d^Ty+(c-B^Ty)^Tx,\quad y\ge 0.
$$
The dual problem is 
$$
\max_{y\ge 0}\min_x L(x,y).
$$
The inner minimum is easily calculated as
$$
\min_x L(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
d^Ty & \text{ if }c-B^Ty=0,\\
-\infty & \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Now for maximization the part with $-\infty$ is not relevant, so we have the dual problem
$$
\max d^Ty\quad\text{subject to }B^Ty=c,\ y\ge 0.
$$